# Using a form with the GET function

Tags: php, html, forms, get

I am wondering if anyone can help
I am trying to use a form with the `get` function, however not having much luck.

Here is my code

```
<div class="row-fluid search-forms search-default">
<form class="form-search" method="get" action="search_results.php">
<div class="chat-form">
<div class="input-cont">   
<input type="text"  placeholder="Search..." class="m-wrap" />
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn green">Search &nbsp; <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i></button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

The search is taking me to the right page but with nothing after `?q=`

Any idea?

Comment: You need to add a `name="q"` attribute to your `<input>`

Comment: @andrewsi beat me to that answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't provided your input a name. So, it has nothing to add to the GET.
add attribute name="" to the  tag.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add name="q":

```
<input type="text"  placeholder="Search..." name="q" class="m-wrap" />
```